# Add multiple csv files into elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have more than 100 csv files which I want to add into elastic search for analysis. How can I do that?

I tried adding csv files, but it was taking only one file. I don't know how to do it. I am new to elastic search and this is my first project. I looked up online but didn't find anything. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: You can use Spark, create a dataframe by specifying the folder containing the csv files and finally save the df to Elasticsearch directly